# How to write a dbf database from a data frame with ordered columns?

Tags: r, dbf

Consider the data frame `yield` below where `T`, `P`, and `TRT` are ordered factors:

```
 yield
Source: local data frame [18 x 5]

     T P    Y  TRT n
1  150 L 90.4 L150 2
2  150 L 90.2 L150 2
3  200 L 90.1 L200 2
4  200 L 90.3 L200 2
5  250 L 90.5 L250 2
6  250 L 90.7 L250 2
7  150 M 90.7 M150 2
8  150 M 90.6 M150 2
9  200 M   NA M200 0
10 200 M   NA M200 0
11 250 M 90.8 M250 2
12 250 M 90.9 M250 2
13 150 H   NA H150 0
14 150 H   NA H150 0
15 200 H 89.9 H200 2
16 200 H 90.1 H200 2
17 250 H 92.4 H250 2
18 250 H 92.1 H250 2
```

When I try and write it to a `dbf` file, I get the error shown below in yellow.

```
write.dbf( yield,
      "/path/to/file.dbf", factor2char = TRUE)
```

> data frame contains columns of unsupported class “c("ordered", "factor")”

My goal is to export `yield` to something `SAS` can understand. In the past, `write.dbf` seemed to be the most straightfoward solution, but I guess I hadn't tried to use ordered factors before. Am I missing something, or is there a better export format which would preserve factor ordering?